# FullSimplify not working

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
 \[Phi]=\[Pi]/8
 G=Cos[\[Phi]]*M+ I*Sin[\[Phi]]*N
```

In the answer to the above code I am getting an answer without any reduction as follows

[image: s]

I have tried FullSimplify, PowerExpand etc. Nothing works. Is there a way that I get the answer in fractional form after finding the value of Cos[[Pi]/8]

Comment: I'm not sure that I see what form you would like to obtain. Could you show explicitly what your desired result should be?

Comment: `g // FunctionExpand // Simplify`

Comment: `M ->m, N ->n` ,Do not use`N`.